# SQL query returns null even when first table is empty (and query has NOT IN) when joined with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**Departments** (has no rows) (has two columns: department_id and name)

**Students** (has the 3 columns: id name department_id) AND
Has two rows:

```
23,"Alice",1
1,"Bob",7
```

My query is meant to return student id and student name when department does not exist.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT distinct s.id as id , s.name as name
FROM Departments d, Students s WHERE s.department_id NOT IN (select id from Departments)
```

That query returns no rows. Should it not return 2 rows given that both departments do not exist?

IF , for example, Department table has a row:

```
1, finance
```

Then the query works perfectly and returns

```
7,Bob
```

Because Alice's department (id 1) now exists.

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem and the expected result

Comment: For example, if you join an empty table, why should that return any row?

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @isaace why should that yield a different result if `Departments`  is still an empty table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you wrote

```
FROM Departments d, Students s
```

This creates a cross-product between the two tables, which is then filtered using the `WHERE` clause. If either table table is empty, the cross-product is empty.

You don't need the cross product with `Departments` if you're using `WHERE s.department_id NOT IN`.

```
SELECT distinct s.id as id , s.name as name
FROM Students s WHERE s.department_id NOT IN (select id from Departments)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Worked like a charm. Also, appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT s.name, s.department_id
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN departments d ON s.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE d.name IS NULL
```

LEFT JOIN returns all record from the Student table matching the records from the Departments table